# Smartface App Studio 4.3 Combobox

Tags: smartface.io

I cannot find combobox or dropdown list box control in Smartface. Can someone suggest a workaround? I was thinking of repeatbox, but it's like list box taking up screen space. Is there any way I can make it to drop down?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pick method. It opens a dropdown list.

You can find an example usage about pick in the link below : 
http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_global_pick.htm

Also, you should add the code below in order to make it work :

```
var touchX;
var touchY;
```

You can add this on Global.Smartface.js or in the page you are going to use pick.